# How to add new data in firebase without the unique keys

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using it in react native app to save the purchase history in firebase with only 0,1,2,3,4.... keys not the system generated unique key

[image]

I'm using this below syntax

```
firebase2.database().ref('user_data/' + my_key+"/purchase_history").push(MY_DATA)
```

I want to remove the key between `purchase_history and 0` and when I add the new data then it should be visible like `0 then 1 then 2 then 3 and so on......`

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question, you should use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method instead of the [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) one, as follows:

```
const newKey = "0";  // Or "1", "2", "3".... 
firebase2.database().ref("user_data/" + my_key + "/purchase_history/" + newKey).set(MY_DATA);
```

As a matter of fact, `push()` generates a **new child location** using a unique key **which is automatically generated** by the Realtime Database (i.e. `-MR99pAG....`).

Comment: Thanks for answer but In case of adding more data then it will always rewrite the 0th value again!

Comment: It's up to you to generate an incremental value for the key. There are only two options: either you use the auto-generated key with `push()` but it will have the format we see in the screenshot, i.e. `-MR99pAG....` (it is based on a timestamp) OR you generate yourself the key because you want to have a specific format (e.g. 1, 2, 3...).
In the second case, you have the full control. Therefore, if you want to have a sequence like 1, 2, 3 you need to generate it.

Comment: Yes I just want the same 0,1,2,3.... can you tell me how to generate this keys like 0123

Comment: "can you tell me how to generate this keys like 0123" => I cannot answer this question, it highly depends on your overall use case. It could be a simple loop to increment a variable. The key is just a simple string or number.

Comment: ok and how I get previous key of value I means how do I get 0,1,2,3 of previous used

Comment: Again, I'm sorry, I cannot answer without more info: it depends on the exact sequence of the writes. You could query the database to get the last value, but I'm not sure it is what you really want: if you don't manage yourself a sequence, it does not make sense IMHO to not use the autogenerated keys.