# Filter firebase data in order by timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to order track ID from firebase by their timestamp (createdAt) but it doesn't seem to order but the function still works. Not sure where I am going wrong on this ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const [trackList, setTrackList] = useState();

//Option 1
    useEffect(() => {
        const userID = localStorage.getItem('id')
        firebase.database().ref(userID)
            .orderByChild('createdAt')
            .once('value', (snapshot) => {
                const firebaseTracks = snapshot.val();
                const trackList = [];
                for (let id in firebaseTracks) {
                    trackList.push({ id, ...firebaseTracks[id] });
                }
                setTrackList(trackList);
            });
    }, []);


//Option 2
useEffect(() => {
        const userID = localStorage.getItem('id')
        const trackRef = firebase.database().ref(userID).orderByChild("createdAt").limitToLast(100);
        trackRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(symptomSnapshot => {
                const trackList = [];
                const firebaseTracks = symptomSnapshot.val();
                for (let id in firebaseTracks) {
                    trackList.push({ id, ...firebaseTracks[id] });
                }
                console.log(firebaseTracks)
            });
            setTrackList(trackList);
        });
    }, []);
```

Comment: Hey Frank your code below worked perfectly but I firstly needed to fix my initial function. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747619/how-to-add-new-data-in-firebase-without-the-unique-keys) This help me rewrite the function to add to firebase which allowed the below code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you call `snapshot.val()` here:

```
firebase.database().ref(userID)
    .orderByChild('createdAt')
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {
        const firebaseTracks = snapshot.val();
```

Getting the value of a snapshot returns a JSON object, and the keys in a JSON object are by definition unordered.

To process the results in order, use `snapshot.forEach` and then call `val()` on each child:

```
firebase.database().ref(userID)
    .orderByChild('createdAt')
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {
        const trackList = [];
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            trackList.push({ id: child.key, ...child.val() });
        }
        setTrackList(trackList);
    });
```